# Showing that linear transformations $1, T, T^2, T^3 ,\dots $ do not span the set of linear transformations of $ \mathbb C^n$ into $ \mathbb C^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, linear-transformations

Suppose $T : \mathbb C^n \rightarrow \mathbb C^n$, $n \geq 2$ is a linear transformation. Show that the linear transformations $1,T, T^2, \dots$ do NOT span $L(\mathbb  C^n, \mathbb C^n)$, the set of linear transformations of $ \mathbb C^n$ into $ \mathbb C^n$.

So I think one way to prove this is to show an upper bound on the dimension of the space spanned by the powers of $T$? However, I'm not sure how to do this.

1 is the identity map, i.e., $1(x) = x $.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dimension of the space of linear operators is $n^2$, whereas the space consisting of polynomials of $T$ is of dimension at most $n$, by the Cayley-Hamilton Theorem. Thus, since $n<n^2$ for $n\geq 2$, powers of $T$ don't span the space of linear operators.

Alternatively, note that all polynomials of $T$ commute with each other. If these generated all linear operators, then all linear operators would commute with each other, which is false if $n\geq 2$.

Comment: Ah, I see, +1, the characteristic polynomial is a non-trivial combination that equals 0, duh, I should have figured out.

Comment: like your answer. But could you just add a bit more detail for your last statement? Perhaps, an example?

Comment: If you can find a pair of noncommuting $2\times 2$ matrices, then you can make noncommuting $n\times n$ matrices for $n>2$ by just adding $1$'s on the diagonal and having upper-left $2\times 2$ blocks which are equal to the noncommuting $2\times 2$ matrices.

Answer (score 1):

I'll talk about matrices, which is equivalent, and over any field $k$.

Suppose that the powers of a matrix $T\in M_n(k)$ span $M_n(k)$ as a vector space. It follows at once that $T$ commutes with every element of $M_n(k)$, so that it is in the [*center*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center_%28algebra%29) of $M_n(k)$.

Now everyone should know that the center of $M_n(k)$ is one-dimensional and generated as a vector space by the identity matrix $I$. It follows that our $T$ is in fact a scalar multiple of the $I$ and, of course, so are its powers, so that the subspace generated by them is one-dimesional. In view of out hypothesis, this implies that $n=1$. This proves what you want.

**N.B.** The powers of a matrix span a subspace of dimension exactly equal to the degree of the minimal poynomial of the matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, every one-dimensional eigenspace of $T$ is an invariant subspace of every polynomial in $T$. So, whenever a linear operator maps an eigenvector $v$ of $T$ to something that is linearly independent of $v$ (such a linear map exists because $n\ge2$), it cannot be written as a polynomial in $T$.

Answer (score 0):

If the powers of a matrix span $M_n(k)$, then it is follows easily that we have $AB=BA$ for all $A,B\in M_n(k)$. Since there are elements in $M_n(k)$ which do not commute as soon as $n\geq2$, what you want follows.